# SQL Server trigger update(col) true or false if inserted value equals original?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Given this simple example trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER example_update
ON example_table
FOR UPDATE
AS BEGIN
   if update(someColumn) begin
      update example_table SET last_update_date = GETDATE() WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM inserted);
   end
END
```

If the old value of someColumn and the new value of someColumn are equal, does update(someColumn) return true or false?  For example, if I run these two SQL statments:

```
UPDATE example_table SET someColumn=1;
UPDATE example_table SET someColumn=1;
```

Does the second statement fire the if block in my trigger?

Also, am I correct in my presumption that if I execute this:

```
UPDATE example_table SET otherColumn=1;
```

then update(someColumn) in my trigger will return false.

I apologize if this is a repeat: the fact the the function is called update has flooded my search results with update statments (which are very different from the update function), and has made it very difficult for me to pin down this behavior.

Comment: You could probably test this yourself in the time it took to type this question out.

Comment: Yes, but I'm really hoping to get an authoritative link to some documentation, which will address any other interesting bits I may not have anticipated.

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx : "...indicates whether an INSERT or UPDATE attempt was made on a specified column of a table..." - this implies that the update doesn't even have to be successful (e.g. in an `INSTEAD OF` trigger where the update hasn't even happened yet, or an after trigger which may ultimately get rolled back), never mind that it has to successfully change the value rather than update it to what it already was. I don't think there will be definitive, official documentation that will provide the answer you want. But you could test it!

Comment: That link is definitely what I was hoping to find. Update doesn't work with timestamps on sql server 2000? Update returns true even if the triggering statement fails?  Those are the kind of details I wouldn't have anticipated, and could have produced bugs.  Thanks for the answer and link!

Comment: Well I think those limitations make sense. Note that `timestamp` doesn't refer to `datetime` columns but rather `rowversion` columns which are maintained by the system, and are - by definition - always updated. Inside the trigger it is impossible for the code to tell whether the update will ultimately happen - an error could happen later in the trigger, the user could cancel while the trigger is running, an instead of trigger may ignore that column entirely. Again the purpose of the function is to show that a column was *attempted* to be modified.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `UPDATE()` function does not discriminate whether the value has changed or not, only that the column was updated. To do this, you should compare the values in the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo-tables.

Comment: You are Right, the `UPDATE()`function don't do this, but you can do another thing to avoid that. Please see my answer.